# Sequelize Grouping data date by date

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I have three tables: Employees, Locations, and LocationEmployees. When I query the LocationEmployees table, the data is returned like this:

```
 "data": [
    {
      "employee_id": 1,
      "date": "2023-04-24T19:10:05.093Z",
      "Employee": {
        "id": 1,
        "employee_name": "John",
        "employee_surname": "Doe",
        "employee_email": "John@mdp.com",
        "Title": {
          "name": "Backend Developer"
        }
      },
      "Location": {
        "name": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "employee_id": 1,
      "date": "2023-03-24T17:27:29.432Z",
       "Employee": {
        "id": 1,
        "employee_name": "John",
        "employee_surname": "Doe",
        "employee_email": "John@mdp.com",
        "Title": {
          "name": "Backend Developer"
        }
      },
      "Location": {
        "name": "Ev"
      }
    },
    {
      "employee_id": 1,
      "date": "2023-02-24T17:27:29.432Z",
       "Employee": {
        "id": 1,
        "employee_name": "John",
        "employee_surname": "Doe",
        "employee_email": "John@mdp.com",
        "Title": {
          "name": "Backend Developer"
        }
      },
      "Location": {
        "name": "Ev"
      }
    },
    {
      "employee_id": 2,
      "date": "2023-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Employee": {
        "id": 2,
        "employee_name": "John",
        "employee_surname": "Doe",
        "employee_email": "John@mdp.com",
        "Title": {
          "name": "Frontend Developer"
        }
      },
      "Location": {
        "name": "Ev"
      }
    },
    {
      "employee_id": 2,
      "date": "2023-04-26T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Employee": {
        "id": 2,
        "employee_name": "John",
        "employee_surname": "Doe",
        "employee_email": "John@mdp.com",
        "Title": {
          "name": "Frontend Developer"
        }
      },
  ]
}
```

I would like to group the data by date so that each date is at the top of the data, with the other records for that date listed below it. For example, the data return structure should be like this:

```
[
  date: 25-04-2023,
  Location:{
  id,
  name,
 Employee:[
  ....
   ]
}

date: 26-04-2023,
  Location:{
  id,
  name,
 Employee:[
  ....
   ]
}
```

]

Here is my sequelize query:

```
const results = await db.LocationEmployees.findAll({ 
            attributes: [ 'employee_id', 'date' ],
            include: [ 
                {model: db.Employees,
                      attributes: [ 'id', 'employee_name', 'employee_surname', 'employee_email' ],
                    include: [ {model: db.Titles, attributes: [ 'name' ]} ]
                },
                {model: db.Locations, attributes: [ 'name' ]}
            ]
        });
```